# DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. cant get ember work

Tags: ember.js, npm

i am trying to run my ember project and it said my babel is outdate , i update everything and noting work can anyone tell me how should i fix it ?

here is what my npm return error looks like

```
  DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-array-contains-helper -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-array-contains-helper -> ember-runtime-enumerable-includes-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-cli-dynamic-model -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-cli-flash -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-cli-flash -> ember-runtime-enumerable-includes-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> moment -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-moment -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-moment -> ember-macro-helpers -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-composable-helpers -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-elsewhere -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-math-helpers -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-power-select -> ember-basic-dropdown -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-power-select -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-power-select -> ember-concurrency -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-power-select -> ember-concurrency -> ember-getowner-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-power-select -> ember-text-measurer -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-power-select -> ember-truth-helpers -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-sortable -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-sortable -> ember-new-computed -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-truth-helpers -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> ember-world-flags -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> liquid-fire -> ember-getowner-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> liquid-fire -> ember-hash-helper-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> liquid-tether -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> liquid-tether -> liquid-wormhole -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> liquid-tether -> liquid-wormhole -> ember-getowner-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> liquid-tether -> liquid-wormhole -> ember-weakmap -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-crudities -> liquid-tether -> liquid-wormhole -> perf-primitives -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-cli-js-cookie -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-computed-decorators -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-computed-decorators -> ember-macro-helpers -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-network -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-simple-auth -> ember-cookies -> ember-getowner-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> ember-simple-auth -> ember-getowner-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> sl-ember-test-helpers -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> smoke-and-mirrors -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> smoke-and-mirrors -> ember-getowner-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
    DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: emma_drf_forms -> smoke-and-mirrors -> perf-primitives -> ember-cli-babel
    ember-cli: 3.1.2
    node: 6.11.2
    os: win32 x64
```

Answer (score 4):

Very recently, ember-cli-babel version 5 was deprecated, so that future versions of ember-cli would not have to be compatible with modules compiled with that very old version.

The good news is, you probably don't have to do anything, ember-cli-babel 5 still works for now. These are warnings, not errors. "Deprecated" simply means that it is still supported, but may not work in future versions.

Since this deprecation is very recent, most addons have not yet been updated to a more recent version. If you would like to help, please open pull requests on the addons listed in your warnings to update the version of ember-cli-babel used to version 6.