# npm errors. DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli, yarnpkg

I upgraded from ember 2.9.0 to ember 3.4.

I am using `npm install`.

Now I get these deprecation errors (for some packages which I have as dependancies in `package.json`):

```
DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: application -> ember-cli-d3 -> ember-cli-babel
DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: application -> ember-cli-d3 -> ember-getowner-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: application -> ember-disable-proxy-controllers -> ember-cli-babel
DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: application -> ember-message-bus -> ember-cli-babel
DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: application -> ember-simple-auth -> ember-cli-babel
DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: application -> ember-simple-auth -> ember-getowner-polyfill -> ember-cli-babel
DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: application -> ember-simple-auth-token -> ember-cli-babel
```

If I use `yarn`, the above errors go away. `yarn` seems to manage dependancies better and perhaps it isolates the dependancies of dependancies better? Not sure exact reason why.

Could someone explain why it works with `yarn` and not with `npm`?
Also, how I can make it work with `npm`?

I need to make it work with `npm` to go live with it.

Comment: Do you have a `yarn.lock` file? Also this are just deprecations. It will still work. What packages are this?

Comment: it works with without issues with `yarn`. Yarn seems to do the dependancy of dependancy package management very well. However I was hoping to get it working successfully with `npm` since that is the tool that is used for package dependancy at the moment within this project.

Comment: You probably tried this, but try to delete the `tmp` and `node_modules` folder

Comment: What is your npm version? Have you tried deleting package-lock.json if it is >= 5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. cant get ember work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054556/deprecation-ember-cli-babel-5-x-has-been-deprecated-cant-get-ember-work)

Comment: @"Patsy Issa" Thanks. Yes, it sounds like it is the same issue. But the person did not mention in that thread it is only an issue in `npm`. It works with `yarn`. Also the answer was not a good answer and was not accepted. Even though the warning are deprecations, when you use it with `npm`, ember application does not run.

Comment: @Gaurav i am using npm v6. yes i have. I also clear node_modules.

Comment: Ember application does not run? I have many repos with those warnings and the application DOES run.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav you were right. I fixed a bunch of other bugs and then somehow npm now works too. So I dont know what the root cause was but it was defiitely not due to the above mentioned dependancy warnings about ember-cli-babel. I will close this issue. thanks for your help.